# Custom SQL Metrics not working in Apache Superset

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I am trying to create a custom metric using custom SQL in Apache Superset.
I have wrote just simple select but it is not working:

```sql
SELECT SUM(sales) AS "Sales" 
FROM SuperStore
```

I got an error `"syntax error at or near "SELECT"`

I have also tried the SQL this way:

```sql
SELECT "Sales"
FROM
(
SELECT SUM(sales) AS "Sales" 
FROM SuperStore)
```

but the error is same.

I want to create the category level sales by using following:

```sql
SELECT SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS "CategorySales" 
FROM SuperStore
```

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In definition of your metric if you decide to create Custom SQL metric, you should only add part

```sql
SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category)
```

Then you can call your custom metric `CategorySales`

Superset will build your query as

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category) as CategorySales
FROM SuperStore
```

The problem you have is now that when you want to add your Custom metric as

```sql
SELECT SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS "CategorySales" 
FROM SuperStore
```

Superset creates query as

```
SELECT SELECT SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY category) AS "CategorySales" 
FROM SuperStore AS "SELECT..." FROM SuperStore
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the reply @puchal
I have tried add part as well, but it was not working that way too. It give me an error :
"SuperStore.Sales" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

SUM("Sales") OVER (PARTITION BY "Category")
SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Category)
not working both ways.

Comment: Superset create query as :
SELECT "Sub-Category" AS "Sub-Category",
       sum("Sales") AS "SUM(Sales)",
       Sum("Sales") OVER (PARTITION by "Category") AS "Sum(""Sales"") OVER (PARTITION by ""Categor..."
FROM "SuperStore"
GROUP BY "Sub-Category"
ORDER BY "SUM(Sales)" DESC
LIMIT 10000;